# html5,css3,change input color

Tags: html, css, input, colors

Im sorry if I didnt wrote the code properly in this area,this is my first post, I'm getting maniac with this and I don't know how to do more
Basically its a form ,and in the end I have 2 input,submit and reset
and basically what I wanna do its change the background color of the reset one,since the submit one is alright,they are all inside of the same form and same css3,this is how it looks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWlfR.png

```
<div id="contactos" class="page">
            <form class="go-bottom">
                 <h2>Contactos</h2>
                  <div>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required />
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" required />
                    <label for="phone">E-mail</label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <textarea id="message" name="phone" required></textarea>
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Clean" />
            </form>
```

and this is the css3

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 14px/1.4 Sans-Serif;
}

form {
  width: 320px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
form > div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form input, form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  outline: 0;
}
form input:valid, form textarea:valid {
  background: white;
}
form input:focus, form textarea:focus {
  border-color: #f06d06;
}
form input:focus + label, form textarea:focus + label {
  background: #f06d06;
  color: black;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
form label {
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s, top 0.2s, bottom 0.2s, right 0.2s, left 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  color: #999;
  padding: 7px 6px;
}
form textarea {
  display: block;
  resize: vertical;
}

form.go-bottom input, form.go-bottom textarea {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
 
}
form.go-bottom label {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
form.go-bottom input:focus, form.go-bottom textarea:focus {
  padding: 4px 6px 20px 6px;
  
}
form.go-bottom input:focus + label, form.go-bottom textarea:focus + label {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML to add a class to the reset button?

Comment: Your code shows no attempt at setting the color or background color. The title says “color”, the text says “background color”. Besides, reset buttons almost never help the user but often hurt him, so you are probably solving a problem that you should not have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/70ypryon/)

You can style the reset as follows

**Add this to your CSS**

```
input[type="reset"]{
  background-color:yourcolour;
}
```

eg

```
input[type="reset"]{
  background-color:red;
}
```

For your situation, i've done a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/m8foevq5/)..here i have just given a black background to the form..